# Error when importing site: BLANKINTERNET#0 vs. BLANKINTERNET#2

Tags: 2010, site-template, site-collection

I've been working on a SharePoint 2010 site in a development area for a while, and now I've come to export individual sites (rather than the entire site collection) so that I can import them onto my production server.

When I run `stsadm -o import -url https://myserver -filename mysite.cmp` I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot import site. The exported site is based on the template BLANKINTERNET#2 but the destination site is based on the template BLANKINTERNET#0. You can import sites only into sites that are based on same template as the exported site.

Fair enough. I don't think that I can change the site template used on my production server, so I'm resigned to deleting the site collection and remaking it (no content yet, not a big deal).

However, I cannot figure out how to create a site collection based specifically on `BLANKINTERNET#2`. When I go to create the new site collection, I'm only presented with the "Publishing Site" option (_admin/createsite.aspx > Template Selection > Publishing tab). I'm pretty sure this is what I did on both the dev and production servers, so my questions are:

1. why has one used template #0 and the other #2?
2. Is there indeed a way to convert my site collection from #0 to #2?
3. How can I create a site collection based specifically on template `BLANKINTERNET#2`?

Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had same issue when importing from backup. I had to create new sitecollection that matches my backup template. In this case STS#0 however you can pick template that you see in `Get-SPWebTemplate`.

```
Get-SPWebTemplate
$template = Get-SPWebTemplate "STS#0"
New-SPSite -Url "<URL for the new site collection>" -OwnerAlias "<domain\user>" -Template $template
```

I'm not aware of any conversion tools.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/araviraj/archive/2008/06/18/sharepoint-templates-types.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263094.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Following might help:

BLANKINTERNET#0 = Publishing Site (1033)

BLANKINTERNET#1 = Press Releases Site (1033)

BLANKINTERNET#2 = Publishing Site with Workflow (1033)

So you need to select Publishing Site with Workflow.

Comment: Hi Ashish. I do understand the difference, and have found sites that list all the template codes and descriptions. As I said above: "I'm only presented with the "Publishing Site" option" when I try to create a new site collection. There is no "Publishing Site with Workflow" option, hence question 3. Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: This site template is only available if publishing features are enabled on this site (and the parent site). [source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/default-site-templates-HA010174491.aspx#BM4)

Comment: As per him, it is not available while creating a site collection.

Comment: Turns out I was doing something wrong: I was importing a site into my site collection, rather than importing a site into a site. In my question above, 'mysite.cmp' is an export of `mydevserver/site1`, but I was importing to `-url http://myserver` instead of `-url http://myserver/site1` - once I update my stsadm command, things went well.

Unfortunately I cannot mark your post as an answer, because it didn't answer any of my questions - especially given that I had stated that only 'Publishing Site' was an option when creating a site collection. Sorry.